# MySQL: Storing a value from a field that may show up variable times on a form

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, codeigniter

I'm creating a form in CodeIgniter that has a paired value- Companies, and CEOs.  The idea is, while there is only one Company field with one CEO field below initially on the form, there is a button for me to create more pairs of Company-CEO fields.  I have an idea for how to make that appear on the frontend, but I'm not quite sure which is the best way to store it on the backend.

I think in order to combine each Company and CEO field into one value for storing in the MySQL database, I could simply use `CONCAT`.  However, I'm not sure if I should even bother creating such a value.  In any case, how would I handle the fact that there are a variable number of Companies (and thus CEOs) for each record?  Would I have to store Company and CEO within another value?  How could such an array or tuple be handled in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1: Do not combine the values.  It will give you headaches in code splitting and combining.  Make two columns, one for company, one for CEO.

Point 2: In general, when using a database, any time you have a list it gets its own table.

The various JS libraries out there let you handle this with a grid.

Comment: Fair enough- there isn't much of a conceptual reason why I should pair them up.  However, do I really need to create another table just to handle the Company/CEO pairs?  They're only one value out of many.  It just happens there may be multiple Companies.

Comment: Why is this a problem? tables are very cheap - free, in fact. There's no practical limit to how many you can have, other than after a few dozen or hundred it can get a bit tedious keeping the relationships straight

Comment: I would agree with Marc B, the worldwide table shortage is over, tables are now free.  But more seriously, you make another table for the same reason you don't combine two values into one -- it works best if there is a place for everything and everything in its place.