# MySQL: Storing variable pairs of values in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, forms, codeigniter

Original problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687345/mysql-storing-a-value-from-a-field-that-may-show-up-variable-times-on-a-form).

I'm creating a form in CodeIgniter that has a paired value- Companies, and CEOs. The idea is, while there is only one Company field with one CEO field below initially on the form, there is a button for the user to create more pairs of Company-CEO fields.  Also, there will be another page, where I'll take the input from the form and output it something like this:

```
CEO X is head of Company A
```

As such, this does mean I'm going to have to cause these pairs to associate with each other to some degree.  Based on earlier advice, my `Main` MySQL table will look something like this:

```
id int
Attribute1  blob
Attribute2  blob
```

And then I will have a `Company` table:

```
id int
Company text
foo blob
```

Finally, I will have a `CEO` table:

```
id int
CEO text
foo blob
```

The idea is for simplicity's sake, for each record from `Main`, it should be simple enough to figure out which Company-CEO pairs belong to that record, since they all share the same id.  That id is created every time the form is filled out and submitted.  However, **what method could I use to associate each Company with its corresponding CEO?**

Comment: Generally an SQL RDBMS would use a M-M linkage in the form: `[Companies] 1:M [Ceos_Companies] M:1 [Ceos]`. Just create the appropriate PK/FP relationships between them. However, depending on exactly *what* needs to be done/stored will affect the structure. E.g. do you need to record changes over time? Can you rule that a person will only ever be CEO of one company? Etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

YOu're not storing anything in the main table that would identify the ceos/companies associated with the record, unless you're storing it in the blob fields. If you want to allow multiple ceos for a company, you'd need

```
company table (id, companyname)
ceo table (id, ceoname)


company_ceos (ceo_id, company_id)
```

and most likely would want some date information in there so you can say that "John Doe" was CEO from '99 to '08, and "Jane Smith" is ceo from '09 -> present

Comment: Whenever the user hits Submit, there is an id created and associated with the entire Record.  I was thinking of having a similar id column in both Company and CEO, so that all of the companies/ceos are connected to that same id.  Also, there is only one company per ceo and vice versa.  However, the main table (Record) can have multiple company/ceo pairs.

Comment: @Apophenia Overload ... that comment just made my head explode :(

Answer (score 0):

Put a foreign key column in the CEO and Company tables to link them to the Record id:

`Company`:

```
id int
Company text
record int
foo blob
```

`CEO`:

```
id int
CEO text
record int
foo blob
```